# Rails: Correct way of making exception of "Yield" by using "Content_for"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, layout, containers

I have a Rails app, in which I fit my entire website into a 980width container with the following code in my 'application.html.erb' file:

```
    <div class="container_980 white shadow-horizontal">
      <div class="container">
      <%= render 'layouts/flashes' %>
        <%= yield %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Now, I want to make 2 file exceptions for fitting the content within the container. I want the index page and another page to expand across the entire page, so I need to get those two pages outside of the common 'yield' set above.

I tried doing so with:

```
  <% if current_page?(root_url) %>
    <%= yield :index %>
  <% elsif current_page?(:controller => "tracks", :action => "show", :id => params[:id])) %>
    <%= yield :show_track %>  
  <% else %>
    <div class="container_980 white shadow-horizontal">
      <div class="container">
      <%= render 'layouts/flashes' %>
        <%= yield %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and

```
 <% content_for :show_track do %>
   blah blah blah 
 <% do %>
```

THE PROBLEM: The show_track page doesn't load. I did some searching, and it seems like the above method should work, but it's not, and I was wondering if I needed to do something else as the "show" page was made through scaffoldaing(RESTful).

Is there a better way to take out the 2 pages from the container than using if..else conditions?

Comment: Have you tried using `content_for(:show_track)` instead of `yield`?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a better way to take out the 2 pages from the container than using if..else conditions?

This is subjective, but I would use nested layouts, then define the layouts for each page type in the controller.

First your basic top level layout.  I'm calling it "application", the default, but you could call it whatever.  Note how if there's `content_for? :application` it will yield it, otherwise it will just yield.  This is key to the setup.  All nested layouts should follow a similar pattern; in this way they can render further nested child layouts, or be used as layouts themselves.

```
<!-- layouts/application.html.erb -->
<html>
  <body>
    <%= content_for?(:application) ? yield(:application) : yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then for the container, you'd define layout which can be nested inside "application", this one setting up your container HTML and rendering content inside.

```
<!-- layouts/container.html.erb -->
<%= content_for :application do %>
  <div class="container_980 white shadow-horizontal">
    <div class="container">
      <%= render 'layouts/flashes' %>
      <%= content_for?(:container) ? yield(:container) : yield %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render :file => "layouts/application" %>
```

Then just move your conditional logic to the controller, like:

```
layout :determine_layout

protected

function determine_layout
  # pseudocode here, you get it
  (index or tracks) ? "application" : "container"
end
```

---

**You could stop there.  Continue to see how you might further nest layouts.**

However you could go further, and use the nested layout setup to nest arbitrary numbers of different layouts.  Say, for example, that tracks had another content block you needed to fill.  You could define another nested layout, like:

```
 <!-- layouts/tracks.html.erb -->
 <%= content_for :some_other_block do %>
   // stuff that should be in some other block
 <% end %>

 <%= content_for :container do %>
   // stuff that should be in the container
 <% end %>

 <%= render :file => "layouts/container" %>
```

Then in your controller, you'd change your `determine_layout` to set the "tracks" layout for tracks, e.g.:

```
function determine_layout
  # pseudocode here, you get it
  if index
    "application"
  elsif tracks
    "tracks"
  else
    "container"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I think I understand your solution conceptually, but I have a couple questions. (1) why do you render the parent file at the bottom? (2) can you elaborate a little on the controller part? I am a beginner and am slightly confused on which controller I need to put the code in, and what exactly I need to type in.. :(

Comment: and also, if i do decide to use the if..else conditions for now, how come <% elsif current_page?(:controller => 'tracks', :action => 'show') %> isn't working? Is that the wrong syntax to check if the current page is the show page of a RESTful scaffolded page?

Comment: 1.) You render the parent file at the bottom because you need to define the content_for the block first, so it will be available when the parent layout is rendered.  2.) Check out the docs [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Layouts.html) and [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Layouts/ClassMethods.html).  One of the ways to specify a template's layout is via a function.  It's documented there.  If your controllers each only need one layout you wouldn't even need to do this.  You could simply say `layout "container"`, and so on.

Comment: In regards to why tracks doesn't work now, I believe that the syntax for `current_page?` you have should work.  Did you define the `content_for :showtrack` before that part of the template is rendered?

Comment: Yes I defined the content_for :showtrack in the view/tracks/show page. https://gist.github.com/4141717 
I think the main problem right now is that I can't get the current_page? thing to check if it's my show page. If I can't get that to work, I can't use yours too since I need to use it in the below code anyways, correct?
 # pseudocode here, you get it
  (index or tracks) ? "application" : "container"

Comment: I coulnd't say why your `current_page?` isn't working.  Anyway you'd only need logic in the controller to determine the layout if the pages were served by the same controller.  Since you have a tracks controller, you could just make layout named "tracks.html.erb" and I believe it should use it automatically.  If not, you'd just state `layout 'tracks'` in the controller.

Comment: Yes, I created a layout file called "tracks.html.erb", but even then, I only want the 'show' page to be exempted from the container, and all the rest of the pages within tracks controller to still fit within the universal container. If I wanted to make an exemption for all Tracks pages, this solution would've worked, but I don't know how to further separate the show page from the rest. (please see the gist provided in my previous comment)

Comment: like <% if params[:action] == 'show' %>? Hmm, well for now I guess I could just go into every other tracks page and just manually type in container at the top.... although that would be so messy